# Using goto to handle input

Tags: php

The first example is using:

1. `HTTP GET` request to load the page.
2. `HTTP POST`  request submit form.
3. Form's data is stored in session.
4. `HTTP GET` request to load the page.

The second example is using `goto` to "reflow" the buffer, avoiding the additional HTTP request.

1. `HTTP GET` request to load the page.
2. `HTTPPOST`  request submit form.
3. Buffer is flushed & content is displayed.

Furthermore, the last example doesn't use sessions.

**301**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <!-- ow noez! -->
</head>
<body>  
    <?php
    // A very common scenario in user-flow handling is redirecting user to the page itself after submitting form, e.g.

    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
        if (isset($_POST['a'])) {
            // Suppose there was an error & I've populated the error in $_SESSION.
            // Now I would redirect user back to the form. This is because there
            // is markup in the upper template hierarchy layer, e.g. "<!-- ow noez! -->"

            header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);

            exit;
        }
    }
    ?>

    <form action="" method="post">
        <?php if (isset($time)):?>
        <pre>This value is from the past: <?=$time?></pre>
        <?php endif;?>
        <pre>Next time: <?php $time = time(); echo $time;?></pre>

        <input type="submit" name="a" value="back in time!">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**goto**

```
<?php
goback:

ob_start();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <!-- ow noez! -->
</head>
<body>  
    <form action="" method="post">
        <?php if (isset($time)):?>
        <pre>This value is from the past: <?=$time?></pre>
        <?php endif;?>
        <pre>Next time: <?php $time = time(); echo $time;?></pre>

        <input type="submit" name="a" value="back in time!">
    </form>

    <?php
    // A very common scenario in user-flow handling is redirecting user to the page itself after submitting form, e.g.

    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
        if (isset($_POST['a'])) {
            ob_clean();

            $_POST = [];
            $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] = 'GET';

            goto goback;
        }
    }
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Is the `goto` scenario not superior to **301**?

Answer (score 8):

[image: xkcd]
>[xkcd](http://xkcd.com/292/)

Have you considered using AJAX instead? Then your flow is:

- `HTTP GET` to fetch the webpage
- `HTTP POST` via AJAX to submit the data
- Done! Optionally, use JavaScript to update the current view.

Alternatively, you can keep your current code and just move the whole `if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === "POST")` section to be up where your `goto` label is. In other words, restructure the program's flow ;)

Comment: JavaScript is not an option, not now anyway. Your suggestion about moving the logic up is only plausible if there is a way to do it. This is a very basic example after all. Finally, the question doesn't ask for alternatives or to debunk `goto`. Pros and cons between the two options is what I am looking at the moment.

Comment: Using `goto` risks velociraptor attacks. That's enough of a con for me!